# Dropdown value not getting inserted in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've a dropdown where the values are from an array, whenever I try to submit the form the value is not getting inserted into the database, I've tried to check all the possible errors but nothing helped

Array from where I'm getting values

```
 $available_background_types = ['Color', 'Image', 'Gradient'];
```

Dropdown Code

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Choose Background</label>
 <select class="custom-select" name="background_type">
  <?php foreach($available_background_types as $type): ?>
        <option value="<?= $type; ?>" <?php if($user->background_type() == $type) echo 'selected' ?>><?php echo $type; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
</div>
```

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'){
  $background = $_POST['background_type'];
 if($dbqueries->Query('UPDATE users SET background = ? WHERE id = ?', [$background, $userId])){
        header('Location: ../profile-settings');
        }
}
```

I've tried many time, the background field in database remains empty. Its datatype is VarChar.

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` somewhere with `method="post"`?

Comment: Yes, i've specified just didn't mentioned it above